# Converting 2D lidar data to pointcloud

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library, ros

I have a 2D laser scan data, that means I have rotating laser sensor that is giving me distance to the object for each degree (e.i.  60° 2,5m ) and I need to process these data in the OpenCV. On the forum I found out that I have to follow this path: **sensor_msgs::LaserScan** convert to **sensor_msgs::Image** and than to **OpenCV image.** 
When I transformed the sensor_msgs::LaserScan to the ros image format using the this command:

```
projector.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/robot1/base_link",*msg_laser,cloud,listener);
```

I got structure containing the data vector which is full of weird values like **[0] 101 'e'** or **[1] 163 '£'** ... 
When I try to convert this ros image to OpenCV image I am getting error:

```
[ERROR] [1461933013.832914106, 990.212000000]: Error in converting cloud to image message: No rgb field!!
```

It makes sense because the sensor is giving me only intensity values without color. But what should I do with the wrong pointcloud2 format ?

Thank you for every suggestion,
Martin

Comment: do you use a specific ROS packae to get data from your 2D Lidar ?

Comment: if I understood your question correct, you can directly create an OpenCV Mat filled with values from the scan data.